# Parse WebSocket frames

Tags: code-golf, string

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers), every WebSocket message is sent as one or more *frames*. Your job is to extract the payload given a (masked) client-to-server text frame. The steps to extract the payload is as follows:

- ignore byte 1; read byte 2

  - if it is 254, skip the next 2 bytes
  - if it is 255, skip the next 8 bytes,
  - otherwise, continue
- interpret the next 4 bytes as an [XOR-cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) key
- decrypt the final bytes using the (repeating) key and interpret it as a UTF-8 encoded string

For reference, here is an ungolfed solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
frame = open(0, 'rb').read()

pos = 2
if frame[1] == 254:
    pos += 2 # skip 2 bytes
if frame[1] == 255:
    pos += 8 # skip 8 bytes

# read the key (4 bytes)
key = frame[pos:][:4]
pos += 4

# decode the payload
payload = bytes(x ^ key[i % 4] for i, x in enumerate(frame[pos:]))

# output
print(payload.decode("utf-8"))
```

### Test Cases

| frame (octets are represented in hex) | payload |
| --- | --- |
| `81 83 3D 54 23 06 70 10 6D` | `MDN` |
| `81 85 3D 54 23 06 55 31 4F 6A 52` | `hello` |
| `81 FE 01 BD 3D 54 23 06 71 3B 51 63 50 74 4A 76 4E 21 4E 26 59 3B 4F 69 4F 74 50 6F 49 74 42 6B 58 20 0F 26 5E 3B 4D 75 58 37 57 63 49 21 51 26 5C 30 4A 76 54 27 40 6F 53 33 03 63 51 3D 57 2A 1D 27 46 62 1D 30 4C 26 58 3D 56 75 50 3B 47 26 49 31 4E 76 52 26 03 6F 53 37 4A 62 54 30 56 68 49 74 56 72 1D 38 42 64 52 26 46 26 58 20 03 62 52 38 4C 74 58 74 4E 67 5A 3A 42 26 5C 38 4A 77 48 35 0D 26 68 20 03 63 53 3D 4E 26 5C 30 03 6B 54 3A 4A 6B 1D 22 46 68 54 35 4E 2A 1D 25 56 6F 4E 74 4D 69 4E 20 51 73 59 74 46 7E 58 26 40 6F 49 35 57 6F 52 3A 03 73 51 38 42 6B 5E 3B 03 6A 5C 36 4C 74 54 27 03 68 54 27 4A 26 48 20 03 67 51 3D 52 73 54 24 03 63 45 74 46 67 1D 37 4C 6B 50 3B 47 69 1D 37 4C 68 4E 31 52 73 5C 20 0D 26 79 21 4A 75 1D 35 56 72 58 74 4A 74 48 26 46 26 59 3B 4F 69 4F 74 4A 68 1D 26 46 76 4F 31 4B 63 53 30 46 74 54 20 03 6F 53 74 55 69 51 21 53 72 5C 20 46 26 4B 31 4F 6F 49 74 46 75 4E 31 03 65 54 38 4F 73 50 74 47 69 51 3B 51 63 1D 31 56 26 5B 21 44 6F 5C 20 03 68 48 38 4F 67 1D 24 42 74 54 35 57 73 4F 7A 03 43 45 37 46 76 49 31 56 74 1D 27 4A 68 49 74 4C 65 5E 35 46 65 5C 20 03 65 48 24 4A 62 5C 20 42 72 1D 3A 4C 68 1D 24 51 69 54 30 46 68 49 78 03 75 48 3A 57 26 54 3A 03 65 48 38 53 67 1D 25 56 6F 1D 3B 45 60 54 37 4A 67 1D 30 46 75 58 26 56 68 49 74 4E 69 51 38 4A 72 1D 35 4D 6F 50 74 4A 62 1D 31 50 72 1D 38 42 64 52 26 56 6B 13` | `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.` |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Shortest code wins.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Code Golf, and very nice first question!

Comment: Maybe you should add more testcases so at least one for 254, one for 255, one for _otherwise_.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @tsh! The steps are simplified because the input assumes a complete, valid WebSocket frame rather than a buffered HTTP socket. However, the protocol uses the "skipped bytes" to represent the payload length. So, while technically a valid frame, a test case for 255 implies a payload-length greater than 2¹⁶-1. I'll add a test case for 254, though.

Comment: Looks like the 2nd byte is length|0x80, what does the first bit do? (unrelated to challenge)

Comment: @l4m2 The lower 7 bits of byte 2 specify the payload length. For payloads greater than 126 bytes, byte 2 is set to 0xFE and the next 2 bytes are interpreted as an `unsigned short` and used as the payload length. When an `unsigned short` is still inadequate to express the payload length, byte 2 is set to 0xFF and the next 8 bytes are interpreted as an `unsigned long`. Furthermore, messages can be longer if sent across multiple frames, but that is out of the scope of this problem.

Comment: Can we assume the encrypted text will only contain printable (ASCII) characters? (Or perhaps a more specific question: can I assume the encrypted text won't have a leading ␀-byte?)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The encrypted data may contain arbitrary bytes. It is guaranteed that it decrypts to valid UTF-8, however.

Answer (score 12):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 60 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.slice(K=[8,14][a[1]^255]^6).map((n,i)=>n^a[K-4+i%4])+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVXbbiM3DH3vV/CliI14nblJM0bhAOMbUGy7L8U@pQmgnZEdFXPbGSnYv8@SlMZJsXkxbIY8POeQVP5TL2qqRjPYT11f69fz9lVt79V6akylF5@3D8Uqzh4f1EP8@JQI8fgkl@tWDYtFtzLL7X33pB4@f8puze/Z4/L25ubVwhYm2N7Dzp3Pelyfx75dTFhiq@fF3b//3N5dPMALJX1x7TdMGtQ46T87u3hZQSyXy@Ufv1V9N/WNXjf9ZXFe2MVNEUORQlqDyCBJIZKQRxBHIOsbKoC7O/j78OXjOvG/OoE/Y8hOIEsQybX6WTdN/2H96QhRDLsDpId33WNIdyBikCmICPIMshJyCdkRkpg/sdOGcqjThj4xBzPlCbIN5ycgEaGAJILoxPlHzj9ALiie5iBywsd8xMRelLOHNAq9iEwOGWMKNAeJpcwnZqo5JCXEB86RIBP6TrV7xik4R3KviPvmFMdeKfMn/IQihOnxc@qLONgXcbBWFkEL4Xj8gnVloRb7@l6kMeXahHP2XFWwD0eQqLSEtKTaoLFgjdgReQqIDhSXV5yU@Rxmn9kTiu@YW8k8d6w9Ye0FxwXne08E8z@x0ow8pxkdCR/dy1OaHcVR15H5y@Az@SN4LifWUlLf3HtezDPlORKfkrnJWS/Pi@LFPLuSka@68nl2CWNiThb0ZiLwwRzyOSdM6jXPDvm/xQvSgnMMOHvGZw9z3iXyVnC@CLMLsyj5s3g3u192mLwt2EPOoZ0/8c7s5rlEHPd6o7f9oYggHNrkmCNJ4OZ7IUK4zOuN8H56LYQjeI4FM7neXR4wr/dIumLSRfx3rDdjDvuZT8F7xTjez4Tv0XP280V86sLzzdj/NJ/1bgI@5of7Kt9ugfwXvAOC5yXe9RXsbTbfkdeezLdThtl5PqRlE24tu95awfvGOJgv@Gb9zl/xUZdIZ13znhP@jlTIiPM953x@E2R4cwjt3V3TbW7m3S5nnoLv5fT27oW3JebIR@8AYeI9ptfX9q9@1C2YYXIt1H3TjzAZC6rVdgX0BuvKautGULUZzFSZ7gK6MfjHSddYANq4qe1rsLodsNh0lalN7ToLzkKjviE8aOuhNbTq0ilQjfnu1Bq@WtCdaREbWkNfXvCnalfw3ZkJun6yo6tB/9BjZayypu/ANY1qq94jU5KZDHViSDNgMmiFxFvk1HsB2Mqu4UCQylkNZnTIxGs1HYx6GPWz7mo9onAMvPSNG7CdRjqoFPQ0aahM08wOoSAHZ3cxykJHhAD/b@IPN67h@KPSg9WObEQP@qpSusK8yg2mVpYqUMUw9qbWHblITmHTyjWDIt3Qn8@mMgpqPemR/tr2DdFQZJBBO6bgq2vXrz8B)

Input a `Buffer`, output string.

Or [83 bytes in browser](https://tio.run/##bcxRS8MwEMDxdz/FvcgurGubtokF6WAwBBnuxflUW4hptlWytCSx6qevrYIg@HZ33O//KgbhpG17vzJdo8ZjMYpibdQ7HNSH3yo5HS2SsPmeUIROt1LhrijzgGZVKUpa1QljVc1JeBE9oglaMhVqUe5W2bK9zipCRg8FOCjWMJefWuPzjbXiE91kvDxj9Py4jE4/hWH@279dXpQNe2GdujcehwAoJ4TcXsnOuE6rUHcnPKLHRU4hTyFtgGWQpBBzuImBxsCbxQwgiuBhu//fsT@OTSuF7A74Bljyq89K6278Ag), which accept `Uint8Array` as input.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org),  <s>101</s>  83 bytes (@sheared)

thanks to @tsh for golfing the decryption part and the neat dict work!

```python
def n(f):f=f[(*[2]*254,4,10)[f[1]]:];return[x^m for x,m in zip(f[4:],f[:4]*len(f))]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVTLbhNBEDzxH61cskuMtTtvG-Wwa3tv8AOWkQCvwVJiO44jJSC-hEsu8E_ha-iumbEtwWVttaqrq_oxP3_vng5ft5vn518Ph9Wb8NIv-xVtilU5vrtezYvd-Pq7snZcVwNlzdj8GH7pD8VqXi8GqizHi_nYLN7u-8PDfkOfng79ffH44ZZW2z09Dm5pvaFv6x3Dd1dmvBjcvb7phbosU7F3u_16cyg2xVx-LqvHy6v1oHYlCNaSvt1xRlUO9_3HZVEO73c3awbSZbkoh8v-83bZFxfgusikz39evQ81dTOqamqnpKdkDSlNlSNfk27J1uQ02Yq8IdOQd2RmpGp8HdmRYExHbiRfxjDSdWRGwCtyzBBIVVR1wM-An5K3EteerBd-xjMn1xLMhHSVaokYTwacVpNmYRp6akj1pBqqp8A4ckr-S-4EPAEYh1oV6nqJcy0N_cKvJCKckd9LXebhuszDuS4kL8IT-QN8mZTLdWMt8aiRq4CZICugDzNy7LQh3Uhu8hjgkSuyTkvVVOLuyKOhZ5r7jJ5IvIW2BjpbeFfwHhC3wMeeWOjv4NRIz2VGM-Hn7nkts5M4-5pBv0t9lv5YzKWDl0bq-tjzkGeKOYqeBtpc9ot5STzk2TVgPvryeXYKnIwxya-xSQ9jpM9eOKVWnh3rP8WDeOE5Jp4J-NFDj12S3lrgbZpdmkWDbzib3T87LL0N6CEwsvMddqbNc6kQj36r0_5IxAqPbHKNiEraYi1mEJ7u7Eawn9GL8FjMMUDJ8e584jzeo_iqxZfob-HXQMMk6wnYK_DEfircY9Qc58v8UgXzNei_9tnvKPEzPt1Xc7oF6b_FDljMy57VteityXcUvat8O02aXdQjXkbp1szx1gL2DTyMt7jZuPNHfvZldfaV91z4W3HhKuCjZp_fBJfeHGE7u2u5zVHe7SbrtLiX7vTupbelRuR_74Bw8j3q-K7-BQ)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to code golf! This is a pretty good first answer, but input can't be taken as a predefined variable. It needs to be taken through an [allowed input format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Comment: `(p:=[10,4][k]if(k:=f[1]^255)<2else 2)` -> `(p:={255:10,254:4}.get(f[1],2))`

Comment: `bytes(x^q[i%4]for i,x in enumerate(f[p+4:]))` -> `bytes(x^m for x,m in zip(f[p+4:],q*len(f)))`

Comment: the `q*len(f)` is really smart.

Comment: `f[(p:={255:10,254:4}.get(f[1],2)):][:4]` -> `f[(p:=([2]*254+[4,10])[f[1]]):p+4]`

Comment: `def n(f):q=f[([2]*254+[4,10])[f[1]]:];return bytes(x^m for x,m in zip(q[4:],q[:4]*len(f)))` (90 bytes)

Comment: -18: `def n(f):f=f[(*[2]*254,4,10)[f[1]]:];return[x^m for x,m in zip(f[4:],f[:4]*len(f))]`

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>44</s> <s>42</s> 35 bytes

*-<s>2</s> 9 bytes thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)!*

```
4(}.]u:@XOR#$4$])}.}.~3^1-254*@-1&{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVRNaxVBELznVzQmZBNJlvme2SdCZr9OgpCTIFFEEtSLoniS@Nef3TUz@14wBx@mqamu6ureb/sXffdAr3fU0RUp2vG/656m2zfr3l089ne/dzfv3t6enrmzu8vH/rH/az/oa@Pdy5trff5nf3ny49PPX/dC8H5HFzrQaU@d0sY6H2Ia8jjNy9qdf@0vX/UfNXfpzq9O7j9/@U4PVJ52SVOyZGfyjowlFSgq0orC3D2D9E@Qnv/U5FYKmbx5Br8upDSN81N@TXYkrylY8oqiI5cpBnILGY1fZh4EI8yD/DKGkWElNwBvKDBDIqNIrcAvwM8UvdRtJB@Fn/HMyb0EM5FVtZeIieTA6dk@C7PQoyE1ksmkZ2ACBSP/l7cTeBIwAb0U@kapcy8L/cJvpCKchT9KX@bhvszDb0OqXoSn8Cf4cvUt9y29xKPFWwPMhFcJc1gosNNMNsvb6jHBI3dknZ7ULPWw8VjomducMROpj9CWoXOEdwPvCXUPfJmJh/4VTp3MXDJahJ@nF61kJ3X2tUB/qHOW@XjkssJLlr6xzDy1TJGj6MnQFppf5CX11LLLYN58xZadASdjXPXrfNXDGJlzFE7p1bJj/Yd6Ei@cY@WZwI8ZRuySzNYD72t2NYuM33SU3X87LLNNmCEwsvMrdmZsuSjUi1912B@peOGRTdaomKqt9GKGeonbjWA/ixfh8cgxQcl2d7FybvcovrT4Ev0j/DpomJqehL0CT5mnwT0WzSVf5pcuyNdh/jY2v0PlZ3y9r3y4BZm/xw545OWP@nrM1rU7Kt5Nu51csyt6xMtQb81tt5awb@BhvMfNlp3f@NmXt81X23PhH8VFUMAXzbF9E0L95gjb0V3LbQ5tt3PT6XEv6@G7V78tGpXnvgPCyfdou/0/)

Expects a list of numeric bytes as input.

### Explanation

```
4(}.]u:@XOR#$4$])}.}.~3^1-254*@-1&{
                             *@-       sign of difference between
                          254          254
                                1&{    and the second byte
                      3^1-             transform to the correct start byte - 1
                   }.~                 chop off that many bytes from
                 }.                    the head of the input
 (  ------------)                      monadic forks
             4$]                       select the key
           #$                          repeat that to the length of entire message
    ]   XOR                            bitwise xor with the entire message
     u:@                               convert to characters
4 {.                                   remove xor'd key
```

Comment: `4 2 10{~` can be changed to `1+3^1-`.

Comment: @Bubbler thanks!

Comment: `22 b.` is `XOR`. Avoiding dyadic inner train seems to be shorter: `4(}.]u:@XOR#$4$])}.}.~3^1-254*@-1&{` (35 bytes)

Comment: @Bubbler Interesting approach, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```
{Buf(.[^4] «+^«.[4..*]).decode}o{.[(2 max.[1]*6-1520)..*]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/basJAFPyVg0jx0i67m70Y0EDTmJ8IUUSTp9oUpVQJ@SL/wh9LdzYkbR98GWbPmZkz@1mc3k17vNJTSau2jr9K9lF8T1i2UTndb/PN/cYyxdgsn7JDsa8ORVPVLJtIOu4uLBP5zLwILfkUkqY97640Gm9pFVFd0njbjKisTrTkl4UgB4GDIHGglQOJJzcOLHcgACaJnn/1@oFe@wUkKoXpFTP5x5muIQWLk0c3sQ1iLMAMFhoVLHQKkRY6hSgpBubvh723ux/2zHt9isFThUOexMxfWyAFEp4OeeshD02t7nWBBbN9P5/nu/jOnfcNOv6vc/dVG7U/)

(I discovered that I could shave off four bytes by calling `Buf` like a function to create a new buffer object, but the increasingly ancient version of Perl 6/Raku on TIO doesn't allow this syntax, so the link is to a previous version of my code that uses `.new`.)

This is two anonymous functions, composed together using the `o` operator.

The right brace-delimited expression is the first function to be applied, to an input list of integers, assumed to be in the range 0-255.  It returns the tail of that list, starting with the xor key at the appropriate index given by the byte at index 1, `.[1]`.  `.[1] * 6 - 1520` gives 10 if 255 is at that index, 4 if 254 is at that index, and some number less than zero for any other byte.  `2 max` makes that number 2 if it's less than 2, giving the correct index for all cases.

The left brace-delimited function takes that key-plus-payload list of bytes and formats them into the output string.  `Buf(...).decode` takes the list of bytes as the argument to construct a `Buf` object and decodes the utf-8 bytes into a regular string.  The argument to `Buf` is `.[^4] «+^« .[4..*]`.  `.[^4]` is the first four bytes (the xor key), and `.[4..*]` is rest of the bytes (the payload).  `+^` is the bitwise-xor operator, and the guillemets that surround it make it a "hyperoperator" with very useful semantics.  The elements of both lists are xor-ed in sequence, and since the guillemets are pointing leftwards at the list of key bytes, those bytes are cyclically re-read as many times as needed to match the number of payload bytes.  An equivalent construction would be to reverse both the order of the lists and the direction of the guillemets: `.[4..*] »+^» .[^4]`.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 19, 214 bytes

-45, see @Kevin Cruijseen's comments. Thanks!

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){var f=java.util.HexFormat.of().parseHex(a[0]);int l=f.length,g=f[1]&255,p=g>254?10:g>253?4:2,x=p+4,i=x;while(i<l)f[i]^=f[p+(i++-x)%4];System.out.print(new String(f,x,l-x));}}
```

---

### Java 19, 259 bytes

-1 for space between `String[]` and `a`. Thanks!

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){var f=java.util.HexFormat.of().parseHex(a[0]);var p=2;if((f[p]&0xff)==254)p+=2;if((f[p]&0xff)==255)p+=8;var x=p+4;for(var i=x;i<f.length;i++)f[i]=(byte)(f[i]^f[p+(i-x)%4]);System.out.print(new String(f,x,f.length-x));}}
```

### Java 19, 260 bytes

```java
interface A{static void main(String[] a){var f=java.util.HexFormat.of().parseHex(a[0]);var p=2;if((f[p]&0xff)==254)p+=2;if((f[p]&0xff)==255)p+=8;var x=p+4;for(var i=x;i<f.length;i++)f[i]=(byte)(f[i]^f[p+(i-x)%4]);System.out.print(new String(f,x,f.length-x));}}
```

Comment: You don't need the space between `String[]` and `a`.

Comment: Both `0xff` can be `255` for -2; `==255` can be `>254` for -1; you can create temp variables for `f[p]&255` and `f.length` to save some bytes; all `var` including the `p` if-statements can be combined to a single-line `int`; `f[i]=(byte)(f[i]^f[p+(i-x)%4]);` can be `f[i]^=f[p+(i-x)%4]`; `i++` can be moved; and (lambda) functions are allowed by default, so no need for a full program. :) All in total: `h->{var f=java.util.HexFormat.of().parseHex(h);int l=f.length,t=f[2]%255,p=t>254?10:t>253?4:2,x=4+p,i=x;for(;i<l;)f[i]^=f[p+(i++-x)%4];return new String(f,x,l-x);}` (163 bytes)

Comment: [Here an ATO link (which is Java version 18)](https://tinyurl.com/3vn5bcrn) (your code seems to use require 17+) to see it in action. Also, welcome to CGCC! :) If you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. Enjoy your stay, and Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: Oops, I've accidentally changed the `&0xff` to `%255` instead of `&255` in my comment/link above. Also, your `f[p]` - and therefore also my `f[2]` - should be `f[1]` instead. Otherwise the final test case gives incorrect output.

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen!

Comment: Suggest `2<<t/254` instead of `t>253?4:2`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 120 bytes

```
#define g getchar()
x[4];i;n;y;main(){g;for((y=g)>253&&(n=y-255?2:8);n+4;)x[n--&3]=g;for(;(n=g)+1;)putchar(n^x[i--&3]);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LZHdbpswGIalHXIVlSZVQVUl85M2GeomEn4CEc4A2xBX3URwAiSY0JYmZNOuZCc96e5pu5q56w4_6fH7vPL78yX_WuT58_PLU7e5HP3u37P1pmrWZ8VZse7yMnsYyFJ_q98ZldEYJ4NnVTOQvxfGZv8wGJxuCvmjOtTOzwfNzelSHQ4_qR9GstFc6Ibc3zaXl-fa3c0bbAikkC8UQ26f3oKbL_1t9Q-RjR9v_v81nv-8y4uNPjkgBXtH2i8UZ4tn0Zzt9BJVlC7AuEVaFK5ADULeLT1zxNNtBxkpNKJC3yM2T63JnNVhE7pjJAVHuMVISeclaCLuscA-8sRSEkbM6-hE_QAPVVwtrZUSaDH3ceDQfZxGSV4CPeRR7O-WPJma1rL2dAnNoiWzh02ybad-fdTjhnkwBDx7BZRgLBrmgQkfiNXOsx5UES8xxPr9LCbJCgwBSuqF5zjfkjRypU1dcFHRh4Qd8HZv5YotjN16cYT3qUUD5oSNqZbYB3seCwFV7DFuIPZNuI1EAO2BhtwuXADWSjPEgszWewHkngn4OnbmLAIKaXzRuAXxlLp-vbtGav1Z3PtZTF22G_WxClFgU0CEYKVAQJI6kjwCT-l04vq7xx6pY5_ZVEFb26Ik1JEGQ2azFqMuWvagJxVdeTg6pCIgswsdqTnzbR8Qi6Q5GF9JJoAOBFSNkZOwCWhiXorAvk63xKXkWJgq8Xy7rYRwKj79CrkF8x2nJdbEzexaNzXiLeqcE2tvSRQXOn41EHqYoc5ZOqFYLRerUiWZ0kQ8AIjX0cJuTzNE4EqZgPh1dTIRdzmljscJf0S_Vtnj-kr_Cw)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this fails for test case 1 because byte offsets aren't handled properly.

Comment: @sheared I misread the challenge, now it's fixed

Comment: [117 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7LbptAAADVq78iUqXKqLK0vFo7yI1IABssQCwsLyutMMsz7Jq4OOBE7Y_04kv6T-3XlNa9j2bmx2v6pUjT8_n12OWz-a_jW5zlFc2uiqsi69IyOUyZybAV7qVKohJJKjo9MS-FlO8PU7qcnpYF84kT-ZvTjBPFG-56fk0l-l6QmGFLZ7N3_P3ywkrfR7xgJKY9Xqz087Ct_hGM9O0S__9w_v2GL3Lh9sljkd7Hg81qNVrDDX4QSq-KYxssWo-Hzg40wCFdpMtzEtadhf2C9znL0H2VhMrtBjcOdVYLb2L2Vo08NtyUgEKiY1PtSaCwAfblj_AUGyYSOVRFyo41eZcYyNTivRvCIC2B4BDoGg8RCe5kJWp0YeKtYYRVkQZ1e2c0veBSrFsOIMlfgDUX42FqytbBV9pNMoAKkhJZSHhcu36wAyLwgsbWNe05COFqkjcFGRcNy8dPqN4rKauOxS6ze-sxVGITaw6VuRIZYE_cMRCz6gJRCxmyVcNREA-A91adYwPc_twlX7MPwh8)

Comment: [106 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY7bbpRQAEXjo3xFExMDiZMcbrVTMja0wAxMgHA53JpqGA7Xcs7QkRaw0R_xZV7qq9-jXyNm9HXvnbX295fsU5llx-PLY18sLn41b1Be1CQ_K8_oaVXmfValB5phKPJuvL2TCnpinkup2B9osio_cCJ_NS04Ubw6v2S5S0EiEjPeksXiLX-3Os2kb6XEdI8nzvTxf8tIX0_GnzitCc08U68LmpGof-nx9yu-LITrJ5-F-pCMNqs1cONu0b1Q-XWS2GDZ-bzr7EALHNzHunyBo6a3UFDyAWcZeqDiSLneotYhznrpU-ZgNdBno20FiIt1ZKoDDhU2RIH83p0Sw4QiB-tY2bEm72EDmlqy9yI3zCogONj1jPsYhzeyEre6QPkbN0aqSMKmuzHaQfAI0i0H4PTvgDWX88PMlK1DoHTbdAS1iytoQeFh4wXhDojAD1tb17QvYeSuqaIt8XzRsAL0BJu9krHqbOxze7AeIiUxkeYQmaugAfbYmwUJqy4hsaAhW407A5IR8P66d2yAuh-79HN-LvwB) w/ main->function

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> 21 (or 20?<sup>*†*</sup>) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¦¬₅<.S>3sm.$D4£Þ^4.$ç
```

Input as a list of integers; output as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0LJDax41tdroBdsZF@fqqbiYHFp8eF6ciZ7K4eX//0cbGlnqKBgaG@somBnqKFiY6CgYmwLZQCaQMgHKmYPkDUACRrEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##bVTLblMxEN3zFaPQZYl8bY/tIErlm5srxAqJJQKpQBeVoK3aFKlbJH6DDRJsWPMB6Z/wI2Hm2L5JgY2VzD0@c848fHF98vbsdPtp9uLqdL2@fXR5dXa@Pn1PZ@eXN@vHNDu@PXwwy@/WNycf9mIPnw1HU/jiZl3j2833zc/fn788mb986q4/zg8Gv/l29/WNnx/c/dge/Z1jd/H54ebX8fbVLHWUHLmB2JN1ZAJFQ52hMMwOCV/53leWvx35kUImthUzrsh01A/3eTpyPXFHwREbip58phjIr8h2OIVtoRhlW@gpGEGGkfwCeEtBGBJZQ2YEfgX8QJE17iJxVH7BC6fkUsySnKm5VEwkD04WmyLMQU8HqZFspm4AJlCw@lvvLsGTgAnIZZA3alxyOehXfqsR5Sz8UfMKj@QVHrkbUvWiPIU/wZevdyVvyaUeHe5aYJa4lVCHFQVxmsllvVs9JniUjKKTyQwaDxOPg56h1Rk10XgPbRk6e3i38J4QZ@BLTRj6Rzj1WnPt0Ur5pXrRae80Lr5W0B9qnbU@jL6M8JI1byw1T62n6KPqydAWml/0S@Op9S6DefIVW@8sOAXjq1/PVY9gtM5ROTVX653o38WTepE@Vp4l@FHDiFnS2jLwXHtXe5Fxpr3e/TPDWtuEGgKjMz9iZvrWF4N48Wt286MRVh6d5A4RW7WVXMJQt2/aEcxn8aI8jD4mKJn2LlbOaR/VV6e@VH8Pvx4alk1PwlyBp9TTYh@L5tJf4dcs6K9H/V1sfheVX/B1v/JuF7T@jBlg9Iv38jJq69seFe@27U6uvSt61Mui7pqfdi1h3sAjeMbOlpmf@MUXu@arzbny9@oiGOCL5tjehFDfHGXb22vdzUWb7dx0MvZl3L179W3pEPnfO6Ccso9u9voP).

**Explanation:**

```python
¦           # Remove the first value of the (implicit) input
 ¬          # Push its new first value (without popping the headless list)
  ₅<        # Push 254 (255 decreased by 1)
    .S      # Compare:                  -1 if <254; 0 if ==254; 1 if >254
      >     # Increase it by 1:          0 if <254; 1 if ==254; 2 if >254
       3sm  # Take 3 to the power that:  1 if <254; 3 if ==254; 9 if >254
.$          # Remove that many leading items from the headless list
  D         # Duplicate the remaining list
   4£       # Pop the copy, leave just its first 4 values
     Þ      # Cycle this list indefinitely
      ^     # Bitwise-XOR the values at the same positions in the lists together
            # (ignoring trailing items of the infinite list)
       4.$  # Remove the four leading 0s †
ç           # Convert every integer to a character with that codepoint
            # (after which this list of characters is output implicitly)
```

† `4.$` could be golfed to `0Ú` (trim all leading 0s), if the encrypted text is guaranteed to never start with a leading ␀-byte.

Comment: Payloads are only guaranteed to be valid UTF-8. Unfortunately a sequence of `\00` is valid.